# How fix warning: Incompatible Objective-C category definitions. Built with different compilers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swiftlint

How **fix** warning or **hide** this warning?

```
Incompatible Objective-C category definitions. Some category metadata may be lost. '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectcd-godibuwtiefhcbcymdullvwwoxrf/Build/Products/Homolog-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage.o' and '/Users/haroldo.gondim/Developer/project-ios/Pods/GoogleConversionTracking/Libraries/libGoogleConversionTracking.a built with different compilers
```

[image: warning]

Comment: Are you using Carthage or using libraries directly in the app?

Comment: Swift Package Dependencies